# Why is John returning gibberish for cracked hashes

Tags: passwords, john-the-ripper

I've been messing around with John, and when I attempt to crack an SSH hash, I receive this output.

[image]

Any clue why the cracked hash is displaying the gibberish??

I used ssh2john to convert the key to a crackable hash, then used the output in John.

I'm running Kali 2021.2 on a VM, which is fully updated.

I also receive the same type of output when attempting to crack different hash formats as well.

Comment: Related: https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/224109/how-do-i-crack-an-id-rsa-encrypted-private-key-with-john-the-ripper

Comment: Could you recheck you results with an un-gziped rockyou.txt file? Judging by the file extension of your wordlist it looks like it is in gzip format and not raw txt (e.g. you would need to run something like "gzip -d rockyou.txt.gz" before you use the file). That could explain the results when trying to crack a format that has false-positives.

Comment: Ty! The devil is in the details. I overlooked that the rockyou file was still zipped, unzipped it and worked like a charm

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I crack an id\_rsa encrypted private key with john the ripper?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/224109/how-do-i-crack-an-id-rsa-encrypted-private-key-with-john-the-ripper)

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is off-topic and turned out to be simple user error